# Number of rows in multi dimensional array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to get number of rows in multi dimensional array?

**Eg:**

```
NSString *array[][2]={{@"1", @"2"},{@"1", @"2"}}
```

Not number of columns (2) but number of rows.

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const int numRows = sizeof(array)/sizeof(0[array]);
```

But may be it will be better to use NSArray:

```
NSArray* array = @[@[@"1", @"2"], @[@"1", @"2"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using C arrays of NSObjects, which is not recommended. I believe that will cause your NSNumbers to be zombies, since the Objective C runtime doesn't know how to memory-manage pointers to objects that are inside C arrays or structs. Thus it won't be aware that those objects are owned, and they will get deallocated.

It might be that Apple has solved this problem, but I don't think so.

Apparently I was wrong. It seems that the runtime does know how to memory-manage C arrays of object pointers, at least static-sized ones. Interesting. It still can't handle objects inside C structs however. Interesting.

Comment: If he will use just static strings: @"1", @"2", then all will be allright. Also all will be allright with ARC-projects.